# I'm not sure why my nested while loop is stopping after the first iteration

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, scope, nested-loops

I have to write a C program that asks the user to input a string and it returns how many times each letter of the alphabet occurs in the string (ie. a appears 3 times).
for example, if the user inputs the following string:

```
Hello
```

it is supposed to return the following

```
a or A appears 0 times 
b or B appears 0 times 
c or C appears 0 times 
d or D appears 0 times
e or E appears 1 times
(it does this for the whole alphabet)
```

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 1000

int main(){

    char str[MAX];
    int count[26]={0};

    printf("Enter your string \n");
    fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);

    char str1[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char str2[]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    while(i<26){

        while(str[j]!='\0'){
            if(str[j]==str1[i]||str[j]==str2[i]){
                count[i]++;
            }
            j++;
        }

        printf("Letter %c or %c appears %d times\n",str1[i],str2[i],count[i]);
        i++;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

with what I have now it scans for a and then stops after that and just returns zero for every other letter

Comment: You need to set `j` back to `0` each time through the outer loop.

Comment: it would be more obvious if you used `for` loops instead of `while` loops.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

After the inner while loop

```
    while(str[j]!='\0'){
        if(str[j]==str1[i]||str[j]==str2[i]){
            count[i]++;
        }
        j++;
    }
```

`j` becomes equal to `strlen( str )` and `str[j]` is equal to `'\0'` So in the next iteration of the outer while loop the inner while loop has a condition equal to logical false. You need at least to reset the variable `j` to zero before the inner loop.

```
    j = 0;
    while(str[j]!='\0'){
        if(str[j]==str1[i]||str[j]==str2[i]){
            count[i]++;
        }
        j++;
    }
```

The reason of this logical error is that the variable `j` is not declared in  the scope where it is used. Try to declare variables in minimal scopes where they are used.

Instead of the inner while loop it would be better to write a for loop like

```
for ( size_t j = 0; str[j] != '\0'; j++ )
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: A similar loop can be used for the outer loop, too.